# get constants by prefix from one given method

Tags: java, constants

I think it is better and faster to explain by one example, see the example below:

I have two constants: `MY_PREFIX_CONSTANT1` and `MY_PREFIX_CONSTANT2`.

Then one method that puts those two constants in one array.

Then I add one third constant called: `MY_PREFIX_CONSTANT3` but I forgot to add this third constant to the array in this method.

What I want to run is something like a check by which I can notify that the `MY_PREFIX_CONSTANT3` constant was not added to the array.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an enum:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    VALUE1(1),
    VALUE2(2),
    VALUE3(3);

    private final int id;

    MyEnum(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

You can access all enum values as array using `MyEnum.values()`

Comment: Thanks Dirk, The point is to check if any of the 3 constants is not added to the array or enum.

Comment: the trick is to use enum values instead of constants

Comment: Hi Dirk, I read a bit about enum and now I can got better your suggestion. Thank You so much, even it put me in the way for what should be the next for those enum structures. The only one bad point is that when I type the class where the public constants are declared and adding the dot then it automatically suggest me the list of constants, for enum I don't know whether or not it is possible ...

Comment: That depends on the IDE you are using. But the autocompletion should work for enums as well.

Comment: You are right, Finally I found the way to create enums and now everything I had in thought was resolved. Thanks so much